# Using memcache in a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

Do you have to add code to your Rails app to use memcache?  I've added `config.cache_store = :dalli_store` to my production environment and `Rails.cache.write('color', 'red')` works.

I haven't made any modifications to my models, views, or controllers.  When I create and save an object, for example

```
user = User.new
user.name = 'John Doe'
user.email = 'john@doe.com'
user.save
```

it is going straight to the database and not going to memcache.  I was hoping activerecord would use memcache automatically if configured for it.  Is that not the case?  Any good articles on rewriting your models to use Rails.cache (or should this be something done in the controller)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

config.cache_store is only going to be used for configuring the store used in writing and retrieving cache.  This is completely separate from your model data storage.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Are you trying to substitute an ActiveRecord database like MySQL with memcached?  Writing to memcached when you create a new record, instead of writing to a database?

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR COMMENT**

cache_money is doing the write_through using activerecord callbacks.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Look at the line 15-17 and you can see where they call the after callbacks:
https://github.com/nkallen/cache-money/blob/master/lib/cash/write_through.rb

You could accomplish what you need in the same manner.  Just code a custom method and make it available to your models.  Then call the method with after_create, after_update, after_destroy in the model.  If you want to make it happen to all models, you could probably do this in an initializer:

```
#UNTESTED, but should be close
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |model|
  model.class_eval do
    after_create :your_cache_method
    #... other callbacks
  end
end
```

You could then code a module with your_cache_method in it and include it in ActiveRecord::Base, so it would be available to all models

Comment: I think what I want is "write-through caching."  I want new data written to memcache and immediately available to view on the website.  Then in the background, the mysql database can catch up from the data in memcache.  I've found plugins that sound like they do this (cache-money) but they are very outdated.  So if I have to do this manually, where would I put the code to do this?

Comment: unrelated note: you can reference line numbers in a github link: https://github.com/nkallen/cache-money/blob/master/lib/cash/write_through.rb#L15-17

Comment: Thanks for all the great info.  I can see how this is done now, but I think this is going to be more complicated than I want to get in to right now.  I found that there is a maintained and somewhat popular fork of cache-money - ngmoco-cache-money - that is working on updating for Rails 3.  This project does not need to be finished until November, so I think I'll wait and see if the fork gets updated for Rails 3 by then.  It sounds like cache-money is more in line with what I am looking for.

Comment: Upon further research, I think what I want is actually called a write-back cache rather than write-through.  I want to write to the cache and then immediately return to the user interface.  Then, in the background, the cache can be written to the persistent database.  I set up cache-money in a quick rails 2.3 project and discovered there was no improvement in perceived write speed, because it writes to both the cache and the persistent database at the same time and does not return until the data is written in both.  The actually resulted in a drastic decrease in response time (took 10X longer)

Comment: I'm probably going to end up writing my own caching mechanism and using delayed_job to catch up the database with the cache.

Comment: what is the use case for this?  I am just trying to wrap my head around a scenario where performance would be this big of an issue where this would be necessary on writes.  Also, I am curious if you could implement this another way using ajax if you are only concerned about returning to the page quickly.  Also, have you looked into using MongoDB?  Depending on the use case, it might give you enough of a performance boost.  Although I may be wrong, I would think that using delayed_job could result in some concurrency issues if the cache gets updated again before the delayed job finishes...

Comment: It's for an election results website.  I get a text file of about 3000 lines with the candidates for every election in every precinct in our candidate and I need to turn it in to a webpage.  The results get updated about every hour on election day.  [Here](https://github.com/jdinkel/rbElections) is my initial attempt, currently working in the file-uploads branch.  It's probably pretty ugly though, I'm really just a scripter, but I thought I would help the department out and do this on zero budget.